# Making own java method for array length issue

Tags: java

So I was asked in a quiz yesterday to make my own method for size of an array of strings. I was told I couldnt use the .length shortcut. Here was my attempt, is it right?

```
 //doesn't receive array! because it's a datamember in the class already
 public int sizeOfArray(){
      int counter = 0;

      while(arrayName != empty){
         arrayName[counter];
         counter ++;
       }
  return counter;
 }
```

Comment: when the arrayName should be Empty

Comment: "Is it right?" -- Have you tried it yourself?

Comment: size and length are two different things. size is usually used for memory

Answer (score 4):

> Is it right?

No. It doesn't even compile. The basic idea would be to try to provoke an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.`

Comment: Err, by accessing the array with an index until it goes out of bounds?

Answer (score 1):

Well, here's a <strike>cheap</strike> solution that satisfies the requirement (not to mention runs in constant time):

```
Arrays.asList(arrayName).size()
```

See: [`Arrays.asList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29)

Note that this wouldn't work as expected if it was an array of primitives (`int`, `double`, ...). It would always return `1` in such cases. Since we're dealing with a `String[]` specifically, we'll have no such problem.

Comment: So if I return that line in the size method I should be fine?

Comment: @user2604754 Yes, that will work. Probably not what your professor was after, but it will work nonetheless.

Comment: @user2604754 Correct.

Comment: I wouldn't do that. I agree with @arshajii that this almost certainly isn't what your professor is after. It *does* use `.length` under the hood.